# Loop products by category

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I've managed to get this working, but I have a slight bug I cannot fix and hope somebody can help.

I works fine if there is a product in the parent category however if the parent is empty even though the SQL returns the correct results the PHP loop repeats the data depending on how many products there are. ie. 4 products = 4 sets of results. But as I stated if there is a record in the parent category it works perfectly.

```
    <?php $_GET["category_id"]=$category_id; ?>

    <?PHP
    $sql = "
        SELECT DISTINCT JVPCX.category_id,
            JVP.product_id,
            JVP.product_error,
            JVP.product_exchange,
            JVP.product_sku,
            JVP.product_name,
            JVP.product_url,
            JVP.product_in_stock,
            jos_vm_category.category_name
     FROM jos_vm_product_category_xref JVPCX
          INNER JOIN jos_vm_product JVP ON (JVPCX.product_id = JVP.product_id)
          INNER JOIN jos_vm_category ON (JVPCX.category_id =
           jos_vm_category.category_id)
     WHERE JVPCX.category_id IN (SELECT jos_vm_category_xref.category_child_id FROM
      jos_vm_category_xref WHERE jos_vm_category_xref.category_parent_id =".$category_id.") OR (JVPCX.category_id =".$category_id.")";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $list = array();
    while ( $r = mysql_fetch_object( $res ) )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $list[ $r->category_name ] ) )
        {
            $list[ $r->category_name ] = array();

        }

        $list[ $r->category_name ][ $r->product_id ] = array(
            'SKU'     => $r->product_sku,
            'Name' => $r->product_name,
            'Prod_id' => $r->product_id,
            'Prod_error' => $r->product_error,
            'Prod_exchange' => $r->product_exchange,
            'Prod_url' => $r->product_url,
            'Prod_in_stock' => $r->product_in_stock
        );
    }
    ?>

    <table width="70%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle"> Error: <img src="alert.gif" title="Error" alt="Error" />
        </td>
         <td align="center" valign="middle"> Exchange: <img src="exchange.gif" title="Exchange" alt="Exchange" />
        </td>
         <td align="center" valign="middle"> Information:<img src="info.gif" title="info" alt="info" />
        </td>
         <td align="center" valign="middle"> Stock:<img src="stock.gif" title="Stock" alt="Stock" />
        </td>
         <td align="center" valign="middle"> Buy:<img src="cart-icon.png" title="Stock" alt="Buy" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <?PHP

    echo("<BR/>");
    foreach ($list as $catID => $products) { ?>
    <?php 
        print($catID);
        echo("<BR/>"); 
        ?>
    <table width="100%" border="1" class="product-head">
      <tr>
        <th width="20%"> <?php echo("Part Number:"); ?>
        </th>
        <th width="45%"> <?php echo("Description:"); ?>
        </th>
        <th width="15%"> <?php echo("Information:"); ?>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>

     <table width="100%" border="1" class="product">
     <?php   foreach ($products as $prodID => $data) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%">
        <?php print($data['SKU']);
            echo("<BR/>");     
        ?>
        </td>


    <td width="45%"><?php  
        print($data['Name']);
    echo("<BR/>");     ?></td>

    <td width="15%" valign="middle"><?php  

                if ($data['Prod_error'] == "Y"){

            echo '<img src="alert.gif" title="Error" alt="Error" />'; 

             }

                if ($data['Prod_exchange'] == "Y"){
              echo '<img src="exchange.gif" title="Exchange" alt="Exchange" />'; 


             }

    if ($data['Prod_url'] > ""){
             echo '<a href="'.
            $data['Prod_url'] 
             .'">'.'<img src="info.gif" title="info" alt="info" />'.'</a>';  


             }

    if ($data['Prod_in_stock'] > "0"){
            echo '<img src="stock.gif" title="Stock" alt="Stock" />'; 

             }
    ?>  
    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <?php echo("<BR/>"); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it is strange that no one suggested you posting your code - so please post your code

Comment: I've been trying to get this working from another post:

Comment: @AndréGadonski et all you Could have upvoted the first comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Remove `jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_id, jos_vm_product_category_xref.product_list`

```
$sql = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        JVPCX.`category_id`,
        JVP.`product_id`,
        JVP.`product_sku`,
        JVP.`product_s_desc`
    FROM
        `jos_vm_product_category_xref` JVPCX
    INNER JOIN `jos_vm_product` JVP
        ON JVPCX.`product_id` = JVP.`product_id`
";
```

And also you change your loop

```
$list = array();

while ( $r = mysql_fetch_object( $res ) )
{
    if ( ! isset( $list[ $r->category_id ] ) )
    {
        $list[ $r->category_id ] = array();
    }

    $list[ $r->category_id ][ $r->product_id ] = array(
        'name'     => $r->product_sku,
        'whatever' => $r->product_s_desc,
    );
}
```